# Given that $BA \parallel DE$, $AB = BC$, $CD = DE$, and $B$,$C$, $D$ are collinear, prove that $\angle ACE = 90^\circ$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I hope someone can point me in the right direction on the following question.

> Given: $BA \parallel DE$, $AB = BC$, $CD = DE$, and $B$, $C$, $D$ are collinear.
>
> Prove: $\angle ACE = 90^\circ$.
>
> [image]

I've determined that $\angle ACE$ does not equal to $90^\circ$. In the diagram there's two triangles which are $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle CDE$. Both of them are isosceles triangles, because $AB = BC$ and $CD = DE$.

The reason why I'm assuming that $\angle ACE$ does not equal to $90^\circ$ is because $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle CDE$ is not right angled triangle, because in the question or the diagram it does not state that:

- Line $AB$ is perpendicular to line $BC$
- Line $CD$ is perpendicular to line $DE$

If they were perpendicular, then it would make sense that $\angle ACB$ and $\angle ECD$ would equal to $45^\circ$. Since $B$, $C$, $D$ is collinear, I can subtract angles $\angle ACB$ and $\angle ECD$ from $180^\circ$ and get $90^\circ$.

But I also think I might be wrong because $AB\parallel DE$, which would make:

- $AB$ perpendicular to $BC$
- $DE$ perpendicular to $CD$

Thank you for time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Triangles $CDE$ and $ABC$ are isosceles.

Angles $D$ and $B$ are supplementary

$2\hat{E}+\hat{D}+2\hat{C}+\hat{B}=360°$

$2\hat{E}+2\hat{C}=180°$

$\hat{E}+\hat{C}=90°$

Thus $\widehat{ACE}=180°-(\hat{E}+\hat{C})=180°-90°=90°$

$\widehat{ACE}=90°$

*QED*

Hope this helps

$$...$$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

we denote with $\angle A=\angle C$ and $\angle C=\angle E=\beta$ and $\angle B=x,\angle D=y$ then we get
$$\alpha+\beta=180^{\circ}-\frac{x+y}{2}$$ and since $x+y=180^{\circ}$ we get $\alpha+\beta=90^{\circ}$